# Ember CLI - Custom DS.LSAdapter.extend returns undefined

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

I want to save claims in localstorage with a custom LSAdapter.

The app/adapters folder has two adapters: application.js and claim.js. After login I want to save de retrieved claims in de store, like this:

```
claimarr.forEach(function(claimString){

var claimsplitted = claimString.split(" ");

var record = store.createRecord('claim', 
      {
        'type' : claimsplitted[0],
        'value': claimsplitted[1]
      }
    );
 record.save();

});
```

I am not able to create the custom LSAdapter. I am using Simple Auth, and the addon writes data to localStorage!

**adapters/application.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

 export default DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'api/',
    host: 'http://localhost:1336',
    headers: function() {
        return {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };
    }.property().volatile()
});
```

**adapters/claim.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

 export default DS.LSAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/'
    }
);
```

**Brocfile.js**

```
..    

app.import("bower_components/ember-localstorage-adapter/localstorage_adapter.js");

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

**models/claim.js**

```
import DS from "ember-data"; 

export default  DS.Model.extend({

    type : DS.attr('string'),
    value : DS.attr('string'),

});
```

**UPDATE**
Workaround in my logincontroller:

```
controllers/login.js  
actions: {

    login: function(){
      //this.set('currentDate', moment());
      //var now = moment;
        //console.log(this.now);

      var self = this;
      self.set('errorMessage', null);

        this.get('session').authenticate(this.authenticator, {
            identification: this.get('identification'),
            password: this.get('password')
          })

        .then(

        function() {

          function getClaimSet(session){

              var claimSet = [];


              //build claimSet from base64 string
              var claimarr = window.atob(session.content.claims).split(",");

              claimarr.forEach(function(claimString){

                var claimsplitted = claimString.split(" ");
                var record = 
                      {
                        'type' : claimsplitted[0],
                        'value': claimsplitted[1]
                      };

                 claimSet.push(record);

              });

              return claimSet;

          }

        var session = self.get('session');
        var claimSet = getClaimSet(session);
        session.set("claimSet" , claimSet );

        session["hasClaim"] = function(value, type){

          if(typeof(type) === "undefined"){
            type = "Method";
          }

          var foundArr = session.content.claimSet.filter(function(claim){return claim.type === type && claim.value === value;});
          return foundArr.length > 0;

        };
```

I'm now able to use: `session.hasClaim(value, type)`

Comment: what's wrong with your code, and what actually the question is?

Comment: In `adapters/claim.js` it is not possible to extend LSAdapter: `DS.LSAdapter.extend`. I can't figure out what the reason. When I remove adapters/claim.js and replace the RESTAdapater in adapters/application.js   the LSAdapter is found.

Comment: what exactly the error was? You should somehow be able to inspect the error thrown in the inspector. I can't seem to find any issues with this, the issue would probably lie somewhere else.